# How can I filter and count objects in DJANGO template?

Tags: python, django, function, class, models

Hello I justa want to ask this because Im new in django, my trouble is that i want to count how many comments have a post and put it in to the html template.
But the thing is that im using for to gather all the events in the db, but i just want to show only the count of comments that have every event that the "for" are showing.
this is my models, view, and template.
Thank you so much.

MODELS

```
class Event(TimeStampModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    finish = models.DateTimeField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'eventos')
    is_free = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=0, default=0) 
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    organizer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Event, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Comments(TimeStampModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.user.username, self.event.name)
```

VIEW

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'eventos/index.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['events'] = Event.objects.all().order_by('-created')[:6]
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        context['comments'] = Comments.objects.all()
        return context
```

HTML TEMPLATE

```
{% for event in events %}
    <li class="span4 ">
      <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-1">
        <h3 class="titulo-fix" >{{ event.name }}</h3>
          <img class="center-cropped" src="{{ event.image.url }}" alt="">
            <section> 
                <a href="#"><h3>{{ event.category }} </h3></a>
                  <div class="meta">
                        <time datetime="2012-11-09" class="date-1"><i class="icon-calendar"></i> {{ event.start }}</time>
                        <div class="name-author"><i class="icon-user"></i> <a href="#">{{ event.organizer }}</a></div>
                        <a href="#" class="comments"><i class="icon-comment"></i>  comments</a>
                    </div> 
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                  <p>{{ event.place }}</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-1">Leer mas..</a> 
            </section>
      </div>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

I want to show it just in that part of the html where it says comments.. with a tag of course, but i just dont know wich tag or how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a helper method on the model which can help you show the number of comments.

Something like this:

```
class Event(TimeStampModel):
    ...

    def comments_count(self):
        #Your filter criteria can go here. 
        return self.comments_set.count()
```

and in the comments:

```
{{event.comments_count}}
```

[More documentation on the reverse lookups can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

If you are not filtering, as, @MadWombat mentions, you could just do

```
{{event.comments_set.count}}
```

Comment: couldn't he just use `{{ event.comments_set.count }}`?

Comment: Definitely, but OP also mentions about the ability to filter, but does not specify the filter criteria, so preferred this method. - Edited the answer anyways.. thank you

Comment: @MadWombat Thats just works great! gosh, thank you so much..
By the way, wich method you showed me guys, is more secure? thank you so so much

Comment: can you tell me of where it come from that "_set"?
cause I didn't define it anywhere. Thank you so much

Comment: When you define foreign key relationships in your models, Django supplies the reverse relationship. The <modelname>_set is just a default name for the reverse.

Comment: Here is a link to the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/

Comment: @MadWombat thank you so so much, as i say, im new in django, I'm just learning looking for answer to my problem, thank you so much dude!

Comment: You are welcome. This is what this site is for. To help you learn :)